# Segmentation fault without "const char*"

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, segmentation-fault

i have some question.
I try this code and recieve "Segmentation fault" error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

struct Stack {
    int value;
    Stack *next;
};

void push(Stack* top, int value) {
    Stack *ntop = new Stack;
    ntop->value = top->value;
    ntop->next = top->next;
    top->next = ntop;
    top->value = value;
}

int pop(Stack* top) {
    int val = top->value;
    top->value = top->next->value;
    top->next = top->next->next;
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    Stack *top;
    top->next = NULL;
    push(top, 20);
    cout << pop(top);
}
```

```
[10:40:46] [~] >> g++ 3.cpp -o 3 && ./3
Segmentation fault
```

but if i add **const char* test = "";** before **Stack *top;** it works normal:

```
int main()
{
    const char* test = "";
    Stack *top;
    top->next = NULL;
    push(top, 20);
    cout << pop(top);
}
```

```
[10:47:33] [~] >> g++ 3.cpp -o 3 && ./3
20
```

where my mistake?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:c] but have written with [tag:c++] headers and `using namespace std;` -- which is this? Do you want to write C or C++? It's best to pick one and stick with it -- the two are less interchangeable than they once were.

Comment: it just my university exercise, i prefer STL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Stack *top;
top->next = NULL;
```

You are referencing an uninitialized pointer. That's undefined behavior. So anything can happen and it may not be consistent with surrounding code.

I suppose you forgot to actually allocate something for `top`.

```
int main()
{
    Stack *top = new Stack;  //  Allocate

    top->next = NULL;
    push(top, 20);
    cout << pop(top);

    delete top;   //  Free

    return 0;
}
```

*Though I'd want point out that you'll still have memory leaks inside the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    Stack *top;
    top->next = NULL;
```

If this were raw C, you'd be writing a `NULL` into garbage location -- the `top` variable has not been initialized, so it points to garbage. The `->next` will follow your garbage pointer and then write into it at an offset of 4 or 8 bytes away. Still garbage.

Maybe C++ does some magic `struct` == `class` magic initialization for you -- I don't know C++ well enough to comment -- but you're probably still looking at garbage.

Adding the `test = ""` changes the memory layout just enough so that you're overwriting something that is within your process's address space. It's still garbage, so who knows what you broke :) but it didn't immediately crash.

Initialize your `top` variable with something:

```
Stack *top;
top = malloc(sizeof Stack);
if (!top) {
    /* die */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocated any memory for `top`.  Allocating memory will fix the problem (don't forget to free it when done).  Adding the const char * probably just masks the problem by placing another variable on the stack (it's very random and compiler specific that this actually makes the problem appear to be resolved).

Answer (score 1):

Change  `Stack *top`  to  `Stack *top = new Stack()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

struct Stack {
    int value;
    Stack *next;
};

void push(Stack* top, int value) {
    Stack *ntop = new Stack;
    ntop->value = top->value;
    ntop->next = top->next;
    top->next = ntop;
    top->value = value;
}

int pop(Stack* top) {
    int val = top->value;
    top->value = top->next->value;
    top->next = top->next->next;
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    Stack *top = new Stack();
    top->next = NULL;
    push(top, 20);
    cout << pop(top);

    return 0;
}
```